# Invoking access prompt and show it to the user

Tags: ios, objective-c, libgdx

**A little background:**

I developed a game in Libgdx and upload it to iTunes app store. My app got rejected with a following reason: (This is not the question but I would like to give you a little background of what I am trying to achieve)

```
> 17.1 Details

Additionally, we noticed that your app does not obtain user consent before collecting the user's personal data.

Specifically, users scores are posted to a high score feature. Please see the attached screenshot(s) for additional information.

Next Steps

To collect personal data with your app, you must make it clear to the user that their personal data will be uploaded to your server and you must obtain the user's consent before the data is uploaded.

- Starting with iOS 6, there are keys for specifying the reason the app will access the user's protected data. When the access prompt is displayed, the purpose specified in these keys is displayed in that dialog box. If your application will be transmitting protected user data, the usage string in your access request should clearly inform the user that their data will be uploaded to your server if they consent.
```

My app only upload high score to my server. But okay if Apple states that the user should know about this I will make it clear.

**Actual mission:**

I dont know anything about objective-c programming since I made this app in Java. But I know that iOS have some security dialogs which prompts the user if they are Okay to use the following feature or data in the app.

I would like to invoke this kind of dialog (with my own message)

[image]

I also know that it should be defined in my info.plist file, but I dont know how to access it at runtime and show it in my game.

Does somebody have a clue how to open this up?

Answer (score 0):

You could try my libgdx extension for dialog windows: https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-dialogs

or:

You need to interface with platform specifig code: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Use UIAlertView class in your iOS interface implementation to open an AlertView:

Code example:

```
UIAlertViewDelegateAdapter delegate = new UIAlertViewDelegateAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void didDismiss(UIAlertView alertView, long buttonIndex) {
        //handle button click based on buttonIndex
    }

    @Override
    public void clicked(UIAlertView alertView, long buttonIndex) {

    }

    @Override
    public void cancel(UIAlertView alertView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void willPresent(UIAlertView alertView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void didPresent(UIAlertView alertView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void willDismiss(UIAlertView alertView, long buttonIndex) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldEnableFirstOtherButton(UIAlertView alertView) {
        return false;
    }

};

String[] otherButtons = new String[1];
otherButtons[0] = "No";
String firstButton = "Yes";


UIAlertView alertView = new UIAlertView("Title", "message", delegate, firstButton, otherButtons);

alertView.show();
```